# How to setup makeprg for Rust?

Tags: rust, neovim

I'm trying to setup a simple keybind so that I can run some of my simple rust programs with just a click of a key, this is what I currently have in my nvim/after/ftplugin/rust.vim

```
set makeprg=cargo\ run
nnoremap <F11>:w<cr>
nnoremap <F12>:make<cr>
```

The problem is that when I try to press F12 it says

```
zsh:1: no such file or directory: ./main
```

For some reason it's executing ./main, how would I resolve this? Is there any better methods in doing this? If so please reply to the post, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it now, forgot to add a space before ":"